# Given user string input, how to check if object is in array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a reference bot for discord that can be used to look up information (`in this case, cars`) and I'm having `trouble` with a concept. The user is `capable` of running a command to look up car information. The command the user gives might be `$car1`, and `car1` will be stored in the `variable` inputCar. The array `validCars` holds all of the cars that can be looked up, and `car1` is one of them. `car1` is clearly not a string in this case but an object with multiple fields, but I need to figure out how to be able to look up information on the cars given a string input from the user. My question is twofold:

1) I know that the outer if statement won't work because inputCar is a string that the user entered, and the objects in the `validCars` array are objects. How can I properly check if what the user enters (`in string format`) matches the name of one of the objects?

2) Now assuming I can actually determine if the car exists in `validCars` given the user input, how can I access the fields (`name, model, color`) given the user input in order to print them?

This might not be the best way to `accomplish` what I'm trying to do, so any suggestions are appreciated.

```
var validCars = [car1, car2, car3, car4];

var car1 = {
  name:"Corvette Stringray",
  model:"2018",
  color:"red"
};

/***
 ***  car2, car3, and car4 all have the same setup as car1, just different values.
***/

// Scan each message (client.on is discord.js jargon)
client.on("message", (message) => {

  // Potential car name entered by user (message.content is discord.js jargon, 
  //it is just returning the string the user entered without the leading command prefix).
 // e.g. the value in inputCar might be "car1" if the user wanted to see info on car1.
  var inputCar = message.content.substr(1);

  // SHOULD check if this is an actual car. This if statement won't work because inputCar is a string,
  // and the values in validCars are not strings but objects.
  if (validCars.includes(inputCar) == true)
  {
    // Condition when car1 is entered (there would be other cases for the other cars)
    if (message.content == config.prefix + "car1")
    {
      // Print car1 info including name, model, and color
    } 
  }
  else 
  {
    // Invalid car was entered by user.
  }
});
```

Comment: What about using a select instead of a text input so the user can only choose a valid car?

Comment: Please don't put "tags" in titles.  That's what the actual tags are for.   Unfortunately I can't edit the title because there's another edit in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to store the cars id with the car in a Map:

```
 const carByKey = new Map([
    ["car1", car1],
    /*...*/
 ]);
```

Then its quite easy to get the car:

```
  if(carByKey.has(message)){
    const car = carByKey.get(message);
    console.log(car.name);
    //...
  }
```

---

If you really want to get the javascripts variable that has the same name and is in global scope, thats possible with window/global (depending on your environment):

```
 if(message in window){
   const car = window[message];
 }
```

....But thats a very very bad idea.